# Can't connect to Postgres in production

Tags: iptables, firewall, postgresql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to connect to my Postgres instance on a local IP, which I can connect to with no problem using the `psql -h localhost` command. However, which trying to run via rails, I get this:

```
$ rails c production
/home/avishai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PG::Error)
    Is the server running on host "10.61.99.194" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Here's my `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf`:

```
# DO NOT DISABLE!
# If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
# database superuser can access the database using some other method.
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             10.80.85.130/32         trust
host    all             all             10.80.85.130/32         md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

How do I make sure that Postgres can accept incoming connections from localhost as well as on select internal IPs?

Comment: The "address" column is for the originating address, not the local IP.

Comment: Is postgresql actually running?

Comment: Yes, it definitely is. I can connect via `psql`

Comment: Could it be a firewall thing? I am running iptables (it would appear)

Comment: Yes, so what does your firewall look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, try to check this two points:

1) In the file `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf` you have to have this line:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

instead of

```
listen_addresses = '127.0.0.1'
```

You can check it via command `netstat -tpln | grep 5432`. You will see in the output somethink like:

```
tcp  0  0  0.0.0.0:5432  0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1150/postgres
```

If the first IP address is `0.0.0.0`, postgres is listening on the all interfaces, which is, what you want. If you will see in the first IP address field only `127.0.0.1`, postgresql is listening only on the `localhost` interface.

2) Try to check your firewall rules via `iptables -L -n`. In the INPUT chain there must be rule accepting connection to port 5432 from IP adress of server, where are running rails.
You can add this rule via command: `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 10.80.85.130 --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT`

But I think, that problem will be in the point 1).

Comment: Great call on `listen_addresses = '*'`! I opened it up and added the firewall rule and now things seem to be working quite nicely.

Comment: `listen_addresses = '127.0.0.1'` is the default setting in the Ubuntu server. It's more secure and if you would play only on the localhost, it is enough... I can advice you to remove from your `pg_hba.conf` file line: `host all all 10.80.85.130/32 trust`. Line, which ended with `md5` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I had that same trouble.

In my case, it was using the IPV6 Localhost for some reason.

Try this in your pg_hba.conf:

```
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```